# Why can't we re-upvote comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

Out of curiosity, why can't we re-upvote comments after upvoting and removing the upvote? As there aren't any penalties or rewards, I was just wondering, why the seemingly arbitrary limitation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Waffles explained why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment/129032#129032) on MSO.

> We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff
>   from the past. The only use case is undoing a mis-click.